# Data generation incomplete: Python random

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, data-generation

I am trying to write a script to generate data. I am using random package for this. I execute the script and everything works fine. But when I check through the results, I found out that the script fails to generate the last 100+ rows for some reason.

Can someone suggest me why this could be happening?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from faker import Faker;
import random;

## Vaue declaration
population = 3;
product = 3;
years = 3;
months = 13;
days = 30;
tax= 3.5;

## Define Column Header
Column_Names = "Population_ID",";","Product_Name",";","Product_ID",";","Year",";",
"Month",";","Day","Quantity_sold",";","Sales_Price",";","Discount",
";","Actual_Sales_Price",tax;


## Function to generate sales related information
def sales_data():
    for x in range(0,1):
        quantity_sold = random.randint(5,20);
        discount = random.choice(range(5,11));
        sales_price = random.uniform(20,30);
        return quantity_sold,round(sales_price,2),discount,round((sales_price)-(sales_price*discount)+(sales_price*tax));


## Format the month to quarter and return the value
def quarter(month):
    if month >= 1 and month <= 3:
        return "Q1";
    elif month > 3 and month <= 6:
        return "Q2";
    elif month > 6 and month <= 9:
        return "Q3";
    else:
        return "Q4";

## Generate product_id
def product_name():
    str2 = "PROD";
    sample2 = random.sample([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],5);
    string_list = [];
    for x in sample2:
        string_list.append(str(x));
    return (str2+''.join(string_list));


### Main starts here ###

result_log = open("C:/Users/Sangamesh.sangamad/Dropbox/Thesis/Data Preparation/GenData.csv",'w')    
print (Column_Names, result_log);

### Loop and Generate Data ###

for pop in range(0,population):     
    pop = random.randint(55000,85000);
    for prod_id in range(0,product):
        product_name2 = product_name();
        for year in range(1,years):
            for month in range(1,months):
                for day in range(1,31):
                    a = sales_data();
                    rows =  str(pop)+";"+product_name2+";"+str(prod_id)+";"+str(year)+";"+str(month)+";"+quarter(month)+";"+str(day)+";"+str(a[0])+";"+str(a[1])+";"+str(a[2])+";"+str(tax)+";"+str(a[3]);
                    print(rows,file=result_log);
                    #print (rows);
    tax = tax+1;
```

Comment: Are you *closing* the `result_log` file at any point?

Comment: Note: Python may *tolerate* the `;` semicolons, but they are not required. Please remove them.

Comment: Hello @MartijnPieters Thanks for pointing out the error. I had to just close it and it works fine. I will remove the semi colons as per u r suggestion. What is u r opinion on the quality of the code? Just to ahve an opinion!

Comment: You can replace the body of `def quarter(month):` with `return ('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4')[(month-1)/3]`

Comment: @JonClements U r right.. I meant code rerview!!

Comment: @JonClements: ugh. Yes, Post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Freudian slip?

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for your suggestion. Appreciate it. I tried to make the changes but I end up with an error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not float". But I see **string** in the tuple :O

Comment: Sangamesh, I didn't notice the Python 3 tag.  Substitute // in place of / to get integer truncating division, ie `return ('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4')[(month-1)//3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close a file to have the buffers flushed:

```
result_log.close()
```

Better still, use the file object as a context manager and have the `with` statement close it for you when the block exits:

```
filename = "C:/Users/Sangamesh.sangamad/Dropbox/Thesis/Data Preparation/GenData.csv"
with result_log = open(filename, 'w'):
    # code writing to result_log
```

Rather than manually writing strings with delimiters in between, you should really use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

# ..

column_names = (
    "Population_ID", "Product_Name", "Product_ID", "Year",
    "Month", "Day", "Quantity_sold", "Sales_Price", "Discount",
    "Actual_Sales_Price", tax)

# ..

with result_log = open(filename, 'wb'):
    writer = csv.writer(result_log, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(column_names)

    # looping
        row = [pop, product_name2, prod_id, year, month, quarter(month), day,
               a[0], a[1], a[2], tax, a[3]]
        writer.writerow(row)
```